How to reference an module's type from application which uses this module?
I'm currently developing on monorepo, implementing internal module which has additional features base on nestjs-prisma
project structure is as following
     - apps
    |    |_serviceA
    |        |_node_modules
    |             |_myPrismaModule (install built version of internal)
    |        |_src
    |           |_generated
    |               |_client
    |                   |_default.js (where my required type lies in)
    |
    |- internal
    |     |_myPrismaModule

Since I'm using Prisma, PrismaClient & Prisma type will defer across all service , cuz its type is defined by how developer designs the prisma schema.
The problem I'm facing is that I can't reference the type properly after interna module build.. (actually I can't guarantee whether this problem is reference problem or not..)
My implementation is the following code, previously it worked well but after changes it started not to reference well.
//previous
import {Prisma, PrismaClient} from "@prisma/client"

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, 'query' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error'>
  implements OnModuleInit{...}


------

// current


async function getPrismaClientType() {
  const {Prisma, PrismaClient} = await import(
    "~~absolutePath~~/src/apps/serviceA/src/generated/client/default.js'"
  );
  return PrismaClient as PrismaClient<
   Prisma.PrismaClientOptions,
    'query' | 'info' | 'warn' | 'error'
  >;
}
@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends (await getPrismaClientType())
  implements OnModuleInit{...}


It throwed Cannot find namespace 'Prisma' but I just to proceed I just comment @ts-ignore in this case.
And In service workspace, whenever I try to access type like below, compiler just thinks type as "any".. any advise in this??
  prismaService.banner.findMany // banner is any

